# Creating hashtag field for parse in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tags

I have a textfield that I want to read as a string and then split based on " " aand create an array to post to my parse server. What I have so far is the following:

```
var tagString: String    

let tagString = tagField.text
var tagArr = split (tagString {$0 == " "})

let firstTag: String = tagArr[0]
let secondTag: String = tagArr[1]
let thirdTag: String = tagArr[2]
let fourthTag: String = tagArr[3]
let fifthTag: String = tagArr[4]
```

however this gives me an error on the tagArr line saying that it cannot invoke 'tagString'.

I am also uncertain as to if this is a good way of taking care of tags? Ideally i would like to have the field split them automatically (real time as the user types) but thats dev2.0 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having trouble invoking `tagString` because you define it twice - once as a variable and again as a constant. Try removing the line:

```
var tagString: String
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post all of your code? Try putting this inside a function, like viewDidLoad.